# ActionScript: how can I get xml nodes by attributes

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have XML below

```
<node id="id1"/><node id="id2"/>...
<edge id="eid1" fromId="id1" toId="id2"/>
<edge id="eid2" fromId="id3" toId="id1"/>
<edge id="eid3" fromId="id2" toId="id4"/>
```

Now I need get all edge base on nodeId,

```
nodeId = id1  -> eid1, eid2
nodeId = id2  -> eid1, eid3
nodeId = id3  -> eid2
nodeId = id5  -> Null
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `document.edges.(@fromId == "id1")`, where `document` is your XML object. 
You may also iterate through edges to find ones you need:

```
for each (var edge:XML in document.elements("edge"))
{
    if (edge.@fromId == "id1")
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var x:XML = <graph>
    <node id="id1"/>
    <node id="id2"/>
    <node id="id3"/>
    <node id="id4"/>
    <node id="id5"/>
    <edge id="eid1" fromId="id1" toId="id2"/>
    <edge id="eid2" fromId="id3" toId="id1"/>
    <edge id="eid3" fromId="id2" toId="id4"/>
</graph>;

var nodes:XMLList = x.node;
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++)
{
  var edges = x.edge.(@fromId == nodes[i].@id || @toId == nodes[i].@id);
  trace("Node #" + nodes[i].@id + " " + edges.length());
  for(var j = 0; j < edges.length(); j++)
     trace(edges[j].@id.toString());
}
```

Output:

```
Node #id1 2
eid1
eid2
Node #id2 2
eid1
eid3
Node #id3 1
eid2
Node #id4 1
eid3
Node #id5 0
```